# D3 Enter() function returns null after data source update

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have the following object:

```
var dataInfo = d3.select("#" + chartRenderDiv)
        .select(".labelLayer")
        .selectAll(".labelNode")
        .data(labelsData, function(d){return d.id;});
```

After that, I correspond it to create SVG elements based on it:

```
var labelContainer = dataInfo.enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "labelNode")
        .attr("cursor","pointer")
        .call(dragInteractive);
```

And finally I let go of the variable:

```
labels.exit().remove();
```

The code works perfectly fine, however when I am re-drawing, while `label` keeps getting the updates from updated data source, `labelContainer` will be an array of null elements.

What is the cause of this null return value and how it should be done so that it always gets the updates and does not return an array of nulls?

**UPDATE**: LabelsData is an array of object with size 183. Here is a sample of one entry of the array:

```
id: "AF"
labelPos: Array[2]
labelPosition: "top-right"
name: "Afghanistan"
neighbourhood: Object
size: 33397058
x: 1349.696941 
y: 60.524
```

It gets updated frequently and based on its changed, it should change the SVG elements actually.

Comment: It isn't clear what 'labels' is; could you post a fiddle or bl.ocks.org ?

Comment: updated the question, Adam Pearce.

Comment: Still not clear what "labels.exit().remove();" does or what labels is, if you post an example isolating your issue, you'll have better luck getting an answer.

Comment: Well, if you cannot answer something, better not to trouble me with "more info" scenarios. Your questions has nothing to do with "what will be label". This is a core D3 function. I already posted the content of dataInfo and from the code (even if you are not super smart) you can understand that they are wrapped inside a g element. They will become "Text Labels" showing some info.

Comment: Can you please post the full code so that we can see your redraw code?

Comment: Here is the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/mEHJD/